# When reapplying, does it pose negative effect in the admission process if you use the similar personal statement?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I was reapplying the same institution that rejected me last year. Last year, I didn't reach any potential supervisors and this year, one professor told me that he would assist me. I thought the personal statement last year was not the main problem for rejection so I reused it. I added two lines to update my background information. And I reworded two paragraphs though they express the same meaning and intention.

I just realized this problem after I submitting my application. Will the selection committee check my previous application? Will it pose negative effect? I really don't want to mess it up with this opportunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is unlikely that anyone would have the ability to discover this repetition (at my institution we don't store applications from previous years), and even if they could there is no reason they would look at your previous application.